# Subscribing to events with = instead of +=

Tags: c#, events

Is there anything wrong with subscribing to event with

```
MyPopup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = popupFixCentered;
```

instead of:

```
MyPopup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback += popupFixCentered;
```

For example, if I am changing to different callback from another method I want to make sure I have only one callback subscribed without needing to -= the correct one.

Comment: If you try it, does it compile?

Comment: @sstan yes, it compiles and I have no issues with that. MyPopup is popup created in xaml. Clicking one button I am aligning popup left and from other button I make it centered to button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you didn't try it.  If you did, you would get the following compilation error:

> The event 'XXX' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'YourClass')

The error is pretty clear: you can only use the `+=` and `-=` operators on the event.

If you try to assign to the `event` from ***within*** the class that defines the event, then it will "work". But the reason it appears to be able to assign to an `event` in that case is because it's actually not accessing the event. It's accessing an auto-generated private delegate instance that you may not realize is actually there.

Quoting from [Chris Burrows' article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/08/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-ii-semantic-changes-and.aspx) on the subject:

> outside of the class or struct that defines a field-like event E, binding to the name E resolves to the event itself, on which the only legal operation is calling an accessor; inside the class or struct that defines a field-like event E, binding to the name E resolves to the private delegate field.

To understand this, you need to visualize that when you define an event such as:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

... what you don't see, is that it actually gets translated into something like this *(I'm copying this from [Jon Skeet's article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/chapter2/events.aspx). Also note that the exact code it gets translated into has changed between versions of C#, so it may be a bit different, but the general idea is the same)*:

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _myEvent += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _myEvent -= value;
        }
    }        
}
```

So when you access `MyEvent` from ***outside*** the class, you can only invoke the `add` and `remove` methods through the `+=` and `-=` operators.

But from ***within*** the class, accessing `MyEvent` means something different.  It actually becomes a reference to that private `_myEvent` delegate variable that you can't see, but it is there.  Because this is a delegate type, then you can use the assignment (`=`) operator on it.

---

So, to achieve what you want, you could define a public method in the same class that defines the event, and use that method to set your new event handler.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void setSingleEventHandler(EventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        this.MyEvent = eventHandler;
    }
}
```

But if you are going to do that, then it defeats the purpose of the `event` type.  If you only want to invoke a single event handler at most at any given time, then defining it this way (without using the `event` keyword) makes more sense:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public EventHandler MyEvent { get; set; }
}
```

**References**

Jon Skeet article: [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/chapter2/events.aspx)

Chris Burrows article: (also check out the rest of the series): [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Part II: Semantic Changes and +=/-=](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/08/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-ii-semantic-changes-and.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it. Yes, you can use the `=` operator to assign to an event. (Edit: Apparently only from within the same class)

```
delegate void Foo();
event Foo bar;
Method()
{
    bar = () => { Console.WriteLine("1"); };
    bar();
    bar = () => { Console.WriteLine("2"); };
    bar();
}
```

Produces the output:

```
1
2
```

But if you try to assign from outside the class, it will give you an error.

You can get around this by using a java-style set method:

```
SetBar(Foo foo)
{
    bar = foo;
}
```

Only time I'd ever recommend java convention for external access of properties :)

Comment: You can do it only for auto-implemented events and only from inside the class.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't test it thoroughly enough.